# Can select COUNT(*) produce the next error?

Tags: python, sql-server, pypyodbc

I am using python's pypyodbc to process some sql BULK insertion cmds on a SQL Sever Database. Yet, at the logs I found:

```
    python   load_d 4c24-4ea4   ENTER SQLExecDirect 
        HSTMT               0x000000000336C260
        UCHAR *             0x0000000003A91188 [      67] "\ a        SELECT COUNT(*) \ a        FROM out_table\ a        "
        SDWORD                    67

python   load_d 4c24-4ea4   EXIT  SQLExecDirect  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
        HSTMT               0x000000000336C260
        UCHAR *             0x0000000003A91188 [      67] "\ a        SELECT COUNT(*) \ a    

FROM out_table\ a        "
    SDWORD                    67

DIAG [22003] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int. (8115)
```

Could the COUNT(*) be returning a very big value that "escapes" from the INT limits?

Comment: Is it actually a view you are selecting from?

Comment: no... the COUNT cmd is on the table itself. This table is receiving tons of rows.

Comment: More than 2 billion rows? Then yes it will overflow, see answer

Comment: I think this is the case... and right now I am trying the answer!! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It can. To deal with this issue Microsoft introduced COUNT_BIG-function Please see details here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-big-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15